# form htmlservice issue with passing parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have looked at other posts and am struggling with the same issue of how to pass form values to GAS.  Since GUI editor has been depreciated, I decided to go the *htmlservice* form route.  In this simple code below, I'm just trying to access the form field *aField* and paste it in a cell.

```
function doGet() {

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myForm.html');
}  

function processForm(value) {
  
var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx").getSheetByName("Results-List").getDataRange("B20");    
myRange.setValue(value.aField);

 }
```

This is the HTML template **myForm.html**:

```html
 <html>

 <form id="myForm">
 <input name="aField" id="aField">
 <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick = "sendData()">
 </form>

 <script>
   function sendData() {
    google.script.run.processForm(document.getElementById("myForm"));
}

 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getDataRange%28%29) has a different use. Use [.getRange('B20')](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getRange%28String%29) to get this to work.